# How to delete FTP files base from file list produced by mget?

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I have a vbscript that basically downloads files base on a filename. I want to get the file list and delete the remote files based from that list.

1. List of remote files that were downloaded, redirect to downloads.txt_[systemdate]
2. List of remote files base on item **1.** that were deleted (after successful download), redirect to deleted.txt_[systemdate]
3. Capture any errors in the process of download/delete and
   redirect to a errors.txt__[systemdate] in local

Below is my existing vbscript. I'm currently new in that program. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
' VBScript Client - Inbound Get FTP Files and Move to 'backup' folder 
Option Explicit 
Dim objFSO, objMyFile, objShell, strFTPScriptFileName, strFilePut 
Dim strLocalFolderName, strFTPServerName, strLoginID 
Dim strPassword, strFTPServerFolder 

'Set FTP options 
strLocalFolderName = "E:\TEMP\VENDOR" 
strFTPServerName = "HOSTNAME" 
strLoginID = "USERNAME" 
strPassword = "PASSWORD" 
strFTPServerFolder = "/SGAII/CCDATA/DEPOSITS" 
'Set File name 
strFilePut = "./S*" 

'Generate FTP command 
strFTPScriptFileName = strLocalFolderName & "\FTP_Inbound_Files_from_Client.txt" 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If (objFSO.FileExists(strFTPScriptFileName)) Then 
objFSO.DeleteFile (strFTPScriptFileName) 
End If 

Set objMyFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFTPScriptFileName, True) 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("open " & strFTPServerName) 
objMyFile.WriteLine (strLoginID) 
objMyFile.WriteLine (strPassword) 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("cd " & strFTPServerFolder) 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("bin") 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("lcd " & strLocalFolderName) 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("prompt off") 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("mget " & strFilePut) 
objMyFile.WriteLine ("bye")

'Execute the FTP script. 
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
objShell.Run "ftp -s:" & Chr(34) & strFTPScriptFileName & Chr(34), , True
```